# Emqx authentication webhook retry after failure

Tags: mqtt, emqx

After configuring emqx to use a webhook for authentication when webhook Api is down I have to re-enable it to work again
how can I automate it to retry the connection after restarting the API-backend

[image: this is the configuration]

is there any configuration of connection to modify to fix my problem?